# rredis nested calls cause error .redisError("Invalid argument") in redisZRange() (and probably other functions as well)

Tags: r, redis

Having the following sorted set (just for a test)

```
library(rredis)
redisConnect()

redisZAdd("AsomepossiblychangedtextSensor", 1, "w")
redisZAdd("AsomepossiblychangedtextSensor", 1, "x")
redisZAdd("AsomepossiblychangedtextSensor", 2, "y")
```

it's possible to select it using

```
redisZRange("AsomepossiblychangedtextSensor")
```

Imagine that the text between "A" and "Sensor" can change one could show the name of the key like this:

```
redisKeys("A*Sensor")
```

which returns the full name "AsomepossiblychangedtextSensor".
If I want to combine it and show this set

```
redisZRange(redisKeys("A*Sensor"))
```

an error is returned

```
.redisError("Invalid argument") : Invalid argument
```

It is caused by `f <- match.call()` in `.redisCmd` which takes the call from `redisKeys`

and can be solved (workaround) by storing the key in an R object

```
ak <- redisKeys("A*Sensor")
redisZRange(ak)
```

Is there a better solution for this problem? In the comments we see

```
# We use match.call here instead of, for example, as.list() to try to 
# avoid making unnecessary copies of (potentially large) function arguments.
```

Comment: See https://redis.io/topics/indexes s

Comment: @ItamarHaber: It's not nested in Redis, but in R, therefore it's an `rredis` issue.